# Error with shallow copy byte[] from controller to a byte[] property in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

**Controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(Models.RegistrationModel userReg, HttpPostedFileBase UserPhoto)
{
    if (UserPhoto != null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            UserPhoto.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            userReg.UserPhoto = ms.GetBuffer(); //Remove this line and I get no error.
        }
    }
```

**Model that comes from View**

```
public class RegistrationModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [Display(Name = "User Photo: ")]
    public byte[] UserPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

**View that holds the Registration Form**

```
@model Models.RegistrationModel

@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "Registration";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";   
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "UserAgent", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Registration failed.");
   <div>
       <fieldset>
           <legend>Registration</legend>

              <div>@Html.LabelFor(p=>p.UserPhoto)</div>
              <div><input type="file" name="UserPhoto" id="UserPhoto"/></div>

              <input type="submit" value="Register" />
      </fieldset>
   </div>

}
```

**Error I'm receiving**

> System.FormatExceptionThe input is not a valid Base-64 string as it
>   contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or
>   an illegal character among the padding characters.

```
Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 128396 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1127925655036 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Host: localhost:1274 Referer: http://localhost:1274/UserAgent.mvc/Registration User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
userReg.UserPhoto = ms.ToArray();
```

GetBuffer returns the internal buffer and can be larger than the bytes it contains

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.WriteByte(1);
int len = ms.GetBuffer().Length;
```

*len* will be 256.

Answer (score -1):

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    UserPhoto.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
    userReg.UserPhoto = ms.GetBuffer(); //Remove this line and I get no error.
}
```

You're disposing of the `MemoryStream` after holding a reference to its buffer. You want to do:

```
userReg.UserPhoto = ms.ToArray();
```

Comment: *You're disposing of the MemoryStream after holding a reference to its buffer.*. **No problem.**  Try `byte[] buf=null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.WriteByte(1);
        buf = ms.GetBuffer();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buf));`

Comment: Ahh, so it's more of an issue with the fixed length of the buffer in that it could be larger than the actual data in the buffer. Thanks!